# DIV wont work with float objective c

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, modulus

I'm trying to use:

```
float divAm = (float)theAngle%(float)rads;
```

but its saying that Invalid operands to binary %

theAngle and rads are both of type float.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The modulus operator is a binary integer operator - it cannot be used with floats. You should use fmod() instead:-

float fmod( float numerator, float denominator );

It's defined in math.h. There is also a version using doubles if you need that.

Comment: is there anything for DIV please?

Comment: What do you mean by DIV?  Do you mean integer division?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you need. A normal division operator '/' will work with floats. If you really want to do integer division, then assign your floats (via a cast) to ints, and use '/'.

Comment: yes int division where you have 7 / 3 and this returns 2 instead of 2.3333333